# Merge insert Primary Key violated

Tags: sql, insert, primary-key

So I have the following query which gets a Duplicate PK error
what am I doing wrong?

////////
EDIT
The PK = ITEM & LOC

```
MERGE INTO item_loc_traits il 
USING   (
        SELECT  item, loc, reward_eligible_ind 
        FROM    (
                SELECT  dc_vert.item , dc_vert.loc, dc_vert.actie, 
                        dc_vert.reward_eligible_ind, 
                        MAX(dc_vert.actie) over 
                            (PARTITION BY dc_vert.item, dc_vert.loc) actie_max
                FROM    dc_item_loc_vert dc_vert
                ) 
        WHERE   actie = actie_max
        ) dc_vert
ON      il.item = dc_vert.item
        AND il.loc = dc_vert.loc
WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE   
       SET      il.deposit_code = reward_eligible_ind
        ,       il.last_update_datetime = SYSDATE;
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (item, loc, deposit_code, last_update_datetime, 
               last_update_ID, create_datetime)
       VALUES (dc_vert.item, dc_vert.loc, dc_vert.reward_eligible_ind,
               SYSDATE, 'CNVOBJ_SRC', SYSDATE);
```

Comment: what is the primary key on ? it is hard to say without looking at data. For easy repro post a sample table creation creation script so one can run this and fix the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probaby multiple rows in the merge source for a particular `item, loc`.  You could test this with the following query:

```
SELECT  item, loc
FROM    (
        SELECT  item, loc, reward_eligible_ind 
        FROM    (
                SELECT  dc_vert.item , dc_vert.loc, dc_vert.actie, 
                        dc_vert.reward_eligible_ind, 
                        MAX(dc_vert.actie) over 
                            (PARTITION BY dc_vert.item, dc_vert.loc) actie_max
                FROM    dc_item_loc_vert dc_vert
                ) 
        WHERE   actie = actie_max
        ) sub
GROUP BY
        item, loc
HAVING  count(*) > 1
```

If this returns any rows, the `when not matched` part of your `merge` will try to insert multiple rows with the same `item, loc` combination.  That would result in a primary key violation.

Answer (score 0):

your query

```
SELECT  item, loc, reward_eligible_ind 
        FROM    (
                SELECT  dc_vert.item , dc_vert.loc, dc_vert.actie, 
                        dc_vert.reward_eligible_ind, 
                        MAX(dc_vert.actie) over 
                            (PARTITION BY dc_vert.item, dc_vert.loc) actie_max
                FROM    dc_item_loc_vert dc_vert
                ) 
        WHERE   actie = actie_max
```

is returning more than one value for the same combination of dc_vert.item AND dc_vert.loc.
If you have twice 5, 10 for example, the first line will be inserted and the second wont see the one that was just inserted because it will be comparing with the original data source